# How to remove \r character with sed

Tags: regex, sed

Very simply I have a file that has \r\n at every line break.

```
aaaa\r\nbbbb\r\ncccc
```

I would like to remove the \r character while leaving the \n in place.

I could do this easily in python but it seems to be more elegant with a simple sed command. Is this possible? What expression would do the trick? I can't seem to find any such solution online.

Thank you

Comment: This is what the `dos2unix` utility does. But with `sed` it would be exactly what you would expect. `sed -e 's/\r//' file`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to do it with `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/\r//g' orig.txt > modified.txt
```

Comment: If you specifically want to remove the carriage return before the newline: `sed 's/\r$//'`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to previous answers, if you want to modify the file instead of creating a new one:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' file.txt
```

In case you want to store a backup file, let's say with an extension .bak:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' file.txt
```

This modifies file.txt and creates a backup file named file.txt.bak.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using the terminal on a mac, use this instead to be able to recognize `\r`

`sed "s/$(printf '\r')\$//" orig.txt > modified.txt`